# Hexadecimal calculation: 1C minus 7 for C disassembler

Tags: c, hex, disassembly

My question is simple, no code, just a calculation. Why 1C minus 7 equals 22 in base 10, an array of 22 bytes ?

I'm working on a C disassembler and I want to group variables. So initially we have:

[image]

That will be turned into a single variable:

[image]

I did the calculation in Hexadecimal and the result is 15. I'm confused.

Comment: It's just plain math; in decimal the _difference_ is 21 bytes. The number of bytes from 7 to 28 is 22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display shows you where each item starts.

In the first display:

- `var_1C` starts at offset −1C; it occupies locations −1C, −1B, −1C, and −1A.
- `var_18` starts at offset −18; it occupies locations −18 and −17.
- `var_16` starts at offset −16; it occupies location −16.
- `var_15` starts at offset −15; it occupies locations −15, −14, −13, and −12.
- `var_11` starts at offset −11; it occupies locations −11, −10, −F, and −E.
- `var_D` starts at offset −D; it occupies locations −D, −C, −B, and −A.
- `var_9` starts at offset −9; it occupies locations −9 and −8.
- `var_7` starts at offset −7; it occupies location −7.

Counting the bytes occupied above shows 22 bytes. They are the bytes from −1C to −7, inclusive.

In the second display:

- `var_1C` starts at offset −1C; it occupies locations −1C to −7.

This is also 22 bytes.

Comment: Thanks so much. I noticed that db =1, dd = 4 and dw = 2 bytes. How these are called, Eric ? dd, db and dw ?

Comment: @razimbres: “db” is for “define byte,” “dw” is for “define word,” and “dd” is for “define double word.” In this context, a “word” is two bytes, so a “double word” is four bytes. “Word” is a flexible concept; some other software or authors use it for four bytes rather than two.

Answer (score 0):

To generalize Eric Postpischil's answer,

> For all Real numbers, the number of integers in the interval [n, m] is
> |(m - n)| + 1

The square brackets indicate a closed (inclusive) interval.